# How to add additional attribute to many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, prisma

I have a database that keeps tracks of my (registered) users. Every user can be (and is by default) part of a team. A team groups together multiple users.

Since users can be part of multiple teams, I would like for them to be able to toggle on and off certain teams. When turned off, the team's data won't be shown to that user in the frontend. When multiple organizations are toggled on, all the data is shown simultaneously.

So my question is: How should I go about this architecturally? Is there a "right" way of doing things? I am using Prisma with a Planetscale (MySQL) database, however I do appreciate any theoretical answers as well.

In Prisma, my (simplified) schema currently looks like this:

```
model User {
  id      String    @id @default(cuid())
  name    String?
  teams   Team[]
}

model Organization {
  id      String    @id @default(cuid())
  name    String
  users   User[]
}
```

Technically, I would think that I would simply like to mark a team as "active" or "inactive", but I'm not seeing how to do that exactly. Simply adding an `active Boolean` attribute to the team wouldn't work, since I won't be able to tell which user that applies to, correct?

The only way that I know that works is to have both an ActiveTeam reference as well as an InactiveTeam reference on my user table instead of having just a teams reference. This does seem unnecessarily complicated though and I'm hoping there is an easier way of doing it.

Comment: Use a `team_members` table, with columns `user_id` and `team_id`.

Comment: You can also have `organization_teams` that lists all the teams related to an organization.

Comment: Could you please explain the relationship between organizations and other entities? Does a user belong to one or more organizations or does a team belong to one or more organizations? Please also clarify 'When multiple organizations are toggled on, all the data is shown simultaneously'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@Barmar` said, you can use a juntion table to accomplish this.

The schema will look somthing like this:

```
model User {
  id   String  @id @default(cuid())
  name String?

  userTeams User_Team[]
}

model Team {
  id   String  @id @default(cuid())
  name String?

  userTeams User_Team[]
}

model User_Team {
  userId String
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  teamId String
  team   Team   @relation(fields: [teamId], references: [id])

  isActive Boolean

  @@id([userId, teamId])
}

// Your other models ...
```